# Reading a grayscale image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In MATLAB R2007b, I can't read a grayscaley image using `imread('my_image')`. Every image opens as rgb and BitDepth is 24.
What can I do??

Answer (score 3):

The images are stored as color images with three 8-bits channels. 
If you want to look at their grayscale representation simply convert them to grayscale after reading them:

```
>> colorImg = imread('my_image');
>> grayImg = rgb2gray( colorImg );
```

For more info see [`rgb2gray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html).

Comment: Thanks shai.
But how can I use imfinfo('....') for grayscale image, as I don't read a grayscale image directly.

Comment: @Muhib what info do you need from `imfinfo`? `rgb2gray` does not change the size of the image or its capture time...